# PHP fileupload using jquery,ajax & json

Tags: php, json, ajax

i am trying to upload file to the server but i am unable to do so as the filename contains C:\fakepath\untitled1.doc
following is my jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#save").click(function()
        {
            var id = $("#id").val();
            //alert(id);
            if(id =="")
                {
                    var method  =   "Add";
                    id = "";
                }
            else
                {
                    var method  = "Edit";
                    id = id;
                }
            var title = $("#title").val();
            //alert(title);
            var fname = $("#fname").val();
            var lname = $("#lname").val();
            var day = $("#day").val();
            var month = $("#month").val();
            var year = $("#year").val();
            var city = $("#city").val();
            var addr = $("#addr").val();
            var tel = $("#telno").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var exp = $("#exp").val();
            var reg = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
            var filename = $("#resume").val();
            if(Validate(title,fname,lname,day,month,year,city,addr,tel,email,exp,reg,filename))
                {
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                                url         :   "addResumeAjax.php",
                                type        :   "POST",
                                dataType    :   "json",
                                data        :   {
                                                    method  :   method,
                                                    id      :   id,
                                                    title   :   title,
                                                    fname   :   fname,
                                                    lname   :   lname,
                                                    day     :   day,
                                                    month   :   month,
                                                    year    :   year,
                                                    city    :   city,
                                                    addr    :   addr,
                                                    tel     :   tel,
                                                    email   :   email,
                                                    exp     :   exp,
                                                    filename:   filename
                                                },
                            ContentType     :   "aplication/json",
                            success         :   function(response)
                                                    {
                                                        $("#msg").html(response.message);
                                                        cityBind(response.citydata,response.city);
                                                },
                            error           :   function(err)
                                                    {
                                                        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                                                    }
                        }

                    )
                }           
        }
    );
}
);
```

kindly guide me where i am making mistake.any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Use `serialize()` function in your jQuery. It will carry all your data to your php page. And make sure you have declared `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` tag

Comment: After using serialize() function it carries all data to php file except filename. i checked data using alert box

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS:

```
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
        var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);   // append more data in the same way

        $.ajax({
                url         : 'upload.php',     // point to server-side PHP script 
                dataType    : 'text',           // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache       : false,
                contentType : false,
                processData : false,
                data        : form_data,                         
                type        : 'post',
                success     : function(output){
                    alert(output);              // display response from the PHP script, if any
                }
         });
         $('#pic').val('');                     /* Clear the file container */
    });
```

Php:

```
<?php
    if ( $_FILES['file']['error'] > 0 ){
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']))
        {
            echo "File Uploaded Successfully";
        }
    }

?>
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: it throws an exception like "myFileJqry.js:134 Uncaught TypeError: formdata.append is not a function"

Comment: i am able to upload file using above code but not able to find other form fields data, can you pls assist me in that too?...thanks in advance.

Comment: Use $_REQUEST['filed_name'] to get the value of any field and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link , I hope it will help you.

https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: files is not defined

Comment: which version of jquery you are using ? Do you show me your html files ?

Comment: jQuery v1.11.0 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license

Comment: where i can paste my HTML, i am new to this web site i dont know much options.

Comment: Done title for my paste is "kiran html for fileupload" link for the same is http://pastebin.com/S80PKMJZ

Comment: I am unable to separate your pages. Give the pages individually like php pages and html pages, js pages...

Comment: find the link where i have pasted my .html code as well as .js